# 1-How my profesor reach this solution? 2-How can I use eigenvalues to compute betas?... if there is any way

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, descriptive-statistics

this time I quite don't undertand how the profesor avoid using matrix algebra to solve this exercise.

Statement:

> Below you can see a scatter plot of the data with the three regression
>   lines corresponding to the three levels of the categorical predictor.
>   Using the same two dummy variables you dened in (a), write down the
>   tted regression model (read slope estimates o the graph). You do not
>   have to make a statement about the residuals. Note, that the general
>   regression model with interaction for this case is

[image]

Graph:

[image]

**Questions:**

**
1) What is the procedure the proffesor utilized?

2) How one can use quadratic form and eigenvalues to compuete the betas wich I belibe will be my eigeinvalues for each eigenvector.
I hope I could explain my problem, thanks so much for your help.**